# How to loop in C#?

Tags: c#

I am new in C# and programming. I am currently building a calculator in my program and find a problem in my loop and user input. After the first calculation is done, the user will be asked "Do you want to continue (Yes/No):" What I want is that the input should only this exact "Yes" to continue or "No" to end the console. The statement "Please enter Yes or No only" should keep looping no matter what letters, numbers or characters the user types as long as it's not "Yes" or "No", but somehow the loop only works if user types "yes" or "no". Can anyone help? Thank you

```
using System;
using System.Reflection.Metadata.Ecma335;

namespace calculator_c_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string value;
            do
            {
                Calculate();

                ColorPrint("Do you want to continue(Yes/No):", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
                value = Console.ReadLine();

                while (value == "yes" || value == "no")
               
                {
                    ColorPrint("Please enter Yes or No only", ConsoleColor.Yellow);
                    ColorPrint("Do you want to continue(Yes/No):", ConsoleColor.Cyan);
                    value = Console.ReadLine();

                }

            }

            while (value == "Yes");
        }

            static void Calculate()
            {
                double count = 0;
                Console.Write("Enter first number:");
                double num1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter second number:");
                double num2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
                Console.Write("Enter symbol(/,+,-,*,%):");
                string symbol = Console.ReadLine();

            try
            {
                switch (symbol)
                {
                    case "+":
                        count = num1 + num2;
                        break;
                    case "-":
                        count = num1 - num2;
                        break;
                    case "*":
                        count = num1 * num2;
                        break;
                    case "/":
                        if(num2 == 0)
                        {
                            throw new DivideByZeroException("Error: Division by zero is not allowed");
                        }
                        count = num1 / num2;
                        break;
                    case "%":
                        count = num1 % num2;
                        break;
                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Wrong input");
                        break;
                }
                ColorPrint("Result " + count, ConsoleColor.Green);
            }
            catch (DivideByZeroException ex)
            { ColorPrint(ex.Message, ConsoleColor.Red);}
            
            }

            static void ColorPrint(string message, ConsoleColor color)
            {
                Console.ForegroundColor = color;
                Console.WriteLine(message);
                Console.ResetColor();
            }
        
    }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  This is a good opportunity for you to start familiarizing yourself with [using a debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/328193).  When you step through the code in a debugger, which operation first produces an unexpected result?  What were the values used in that operation?  What was the result?  What result was expected?  Why?  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: *"the loop only works if user types "yes" or "no""* - Which loop?  This one?: `while (value == "yes" || value == "no")`  What "works" or "doesn't work" about it?  Please clarify the specific problem you are referring to.

Comment: @David sorry if I can't explain clearly. So, when the user types yes instead of Yes, or no instead of No, the statement 'Please enter Yes or No only' will keep repeating, until the correct "Yes" or "No" is met. But, if the user types like number, or symbol, the console will stop. It shouldn't be like that, this statement 'Please enter Yes or No only' should keep appearing until the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

From a comment on the question above:

> if the user types like number, or symbol, the console will stop.

Well, yes, that's what it's currently programmed to do.  Look at the steps:

```
do
{
    // unrelated logic

    // STEP 2: "foo" doesn't match either of these values, so this loop ends
    while (value == "yes" || value == "no")
    {
        // unrelated logic

        // STEP 1: The user enters nonsense, such as "foo"
        value = Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
// STEP 3: "foo" doesn't match this value, so this loop ends
while (value == "Yes");
```

If you want that inner loop to continue for as long as `value` is *not* one of those two values, you probably meant this:

```
while (value != "yes" && value != "no")
```

Note: In some places you check for `"yes"` and in others for `"Yes"`, you probably want to either standardize that or make your comparisons case-insensitive.

Comment: I did like what you suggested, and changed the first letter for both yes and no into Uppercase and it works. Thank you for the help :)